# Strange behavior with "which" and "%in%"?

Tags: r

Perhaps, this is a silly question but I cannot realize the answer. I have two vectors 'a' and 'b' that contain strings. Some strings are common between both. However if I do:

```
x <- length(which(a %in% b)) 
y <- length(which(b %in% a))
```

then x is not equal to y. Can anybody explain why?

Thanks in advance!!!.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have duplicate strings in at least one of your vectors.

Example:

```
a <- c("a", "a")
b <- c("a", "b")

which(a %in% b) # 1 2 (length 2)
which(b %in% a) # 1 (length 1)
```

If you want to know the common elements between two vectors without duplicates messing up the answer, you can use the function `intersect`:

```
intersect(a, b) # equal to intersect(b, a)
[1] "a"
```

Comment: Hi thanks!, and yeap you are right, that was the problem. I was mistakenly assuming that both were having unique strings.